# Converting date into PostgreSQL format

Tags: postgresql, grails

I have a date time in format: Mon Jun 11 12:16:14 EDT 2013
I want it inserted in postgres as Date attribute, but postgres always inserts the current date time. I think it is the issue with the format. The normal date format in postgres is something like: 2012-06-13 04:24:45

How could I change Mon Jun 11 12:16:14 EDT 2013 format compatible to postgres?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Show the code that isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [`to_date` or `to_timestamp`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-formatting.html) function.

You give it your string date, and a patten for how to parse the date. For your example it would be:

```
select to_timestamp('Mon Jun 11 12:16:14 EDT 2013', 'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS ??? YYYY');

      to_timestamp      
------------------------
 2013-06-11 12:16:14+01
```

I don't think you can't work with the timezone with these functions unfortunately (hence the ???)

You should also just be able to cast the string like:

```
 'Mon Jun 11 12:16:14 EDT 2013'::timestamptz;
```

Comment: It says you need Integer value for MM.

Comment: I assume you are attempting a different date string that the one you provided in the question, since I typed the above into `psql` without issue. Show the query you are attempting and the error given.

Comment: select to_timestamp('Mon Jun 11 12:12:14 EDT 2013', 'Dy MM DD HH:MI:SS ??? YYYY');
ERROR:  invalid value "Ju" for "MM"
DETAIL:  Value must be an integer.

And after replacing Jun with 06:

select to_timestamp('Mon 06 11 12:12:14 EDT 2013', 'Dy MM DD HH:MI:SS ??? YYYY');
      to_timestamp      
------------------------
 2013-06-11 00:12:14-04
(1 row)

Comment: You are using `MM` where you should be using `Mon`.